# How to authenticate git push to GitHub within an Azure Pipeline Bash task

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

Inside one of our Azure Pipelines I am attempting to push a tag to GitHub but receiving one of two errors depending on my approach.

### No authentication, just a simple `git push`

```yaml
- bash: 'git push origin $(tag)'
```

```
git push origin 2019.07.01.1
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

### Pass `AUTHORIZATION: Bearer ***` as an extra header

```yaml
- bash: 'git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" push origin $(tag)'
```

```
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: Bearer ***" push origin 2019.07.01.2
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/respondentinc/website/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

### Pass `AUTHORIZATION: Bearer ***` as an extra header, using environmental variables

From: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1582#issuecomment-392235276

```yaml
- bash: 'git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: Bearer $env:token" push origin $(tag)'
  env:
      token: $(System.AccessToken)
```

```
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: Bearer ***" push origin 2019.07.01.3
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/respondentinc/website/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

### Pass a Bash script to the credential helper

Based on [bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8705432/bk2204)'s answer

```
- bash: 'git -c credential.helper=''!f() { echo "username=token"; echo "password=$(System.AccessToken)"; }; f'' push origin $(tag)'
```

```
git -c credential.helper='!f() { echo "username=token"; echo "password=***"; }; f' push origin 2019.07.02.9
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/respondentinc/website/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

### Pass a Bash script to the credential helper, using environmental variables

From [bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8705432/bk2204)'s answer

```
- bash: 'git -c credential.helper=''!f() { echo "username=token"; echo "password=$env:token"; }; f'' push origin $(tag)'
  env:
      token: $(System.AccessToken)
```

```
git -c credential.helper='!f() { echo "username=token"; echo "password=$env:token"; }; f' push origin 2019.07.02.9
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/respondentinc/website/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

### Pass `AUTHORIZATION: Basic ***` as an extra header

Tried to mimic the way the default pipeline "Checkout" task does it.

```
- bash: 'git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic $(System.AccessToken)" push origin $(tag)'
```

```
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" push origin 2019.07.02.10
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/respondentinc/website/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

I tried a handful of variations on the above themes with no luck.

What am I missing?

## Update: 2019-07-02

All the above mechanisms are valid ways of authenticating. The issue is that the `System.AccessToken` isn't valid for GitHub. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables) indicates it is for interaction with Azure Pipeline services *only*.

I wasn't able to find a variable for the token provided by the [Azure Pipeline GitHub App](https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines). I don't think it would matter though since it's an [installation token](https://developer.github.com/apps/differences-between-apps/#token-based-identification). I tried using this token with the [GitHubRelease](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/github-release?view=azure-devops) task and it still failed due to a lack of write permission.

To get this working I went with the GitHubRelease task and had to create a new service connection with a new OAuth token that had write permission.

I'm still curious how to get access to a token associated with a service connection from within the Bash task.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Maxim I used the GitHubRelease task and created an OAuth token (within GitHub) specifically for this job. Not ideal. I plan to migrate to GitHub Actions soon.

Comment: I've added my solution as an answer.

Comment: `bash:`… `"password=$env:token"`—you are mixing syntaxes here. Bash syntax is just `$token`; `$env:token` is a powershell syntax.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

1. Create Personal Access Token (PAT) on GitHub

   [image]
2. Create secret variable within your pipeline which will hold PAT

   [image]
3. Now you can use PAT for `git push` in pipeline YAML config:

   `git push https://$(GitHubPAT)@github.com/<your_org_and_project>.git`

Also it seems you need to do these steps before `push` (I'm using PowerShell script step):

```
Add-Content "$HOME\.git-credentials" "https://$(GitHubPAT):x-oauth-basic@github.com"
git config --global user.email "<email>"
git config --global user.name "<name>"
git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

But I'm not sure what of these instructions can be omitted. But following these steps I'm able to do `git push` from my pipeline.

Comment: This saved my bacon, only thing I would add to your answer is this documentation for extra reading :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: One variation on this method, is to store the token in Azure Key Vault instead of being  a secret variable; you would need to add a [task to download the secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) and then use it as a variable exactly the same in your push.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to use Bearer authentication. That's correct for Azure DevOps hosting, but not for GitHub, which uses Basic authentication.

The best way to handle this is to set the environment variable `TOKEN` to have the token that you want (like your attempt), and then run the command as follows:

```
git -c credential.helper='!f() { echo "username=token"; echo "password=$TOKEN"; };f' push $(tag)
```

Any username is acceptable if you're using a token; I just used token because you need *some* username, and it's an obvious choice.

By using a shell function as a credential helper and using echo, which is a shell built-in, your credentials won't appear in the logs or process output.

Comment: I gave this a shot but I'm still getting `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/respondentinc/website/': The requested URL returned error: 400`. Leads me to believe this isn't an authentication issue but instead some kind of scoping/environmental issue. Also, I've updated my question to include this method.